# View with Group By Causes Invalid Identifier on AVG Alias

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle says I have an invalid identifier, I have looked at other solutions saying to encapsulate in a subquery but I cannot get that to work so far. I am thinking possibly the join may have something to do with it.

I am trying to create a view showing vendor names, and for each vendor, the average amount of time between when an invoice was created and paid for (each vendor has multiple invoices), but only if that average is greater than or equal to 1.5. I am then to sort the list in descending order by this average.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Vend_Date_Avgs AS
SELECT V.Vendor_Name, AVG(I.Invoice_Due_Date - I.Invoice_Date) AS Avg_Between
FROM Vendors V, Invoices I
WHERE V.Vendor_ID = I.Vendor_ID
GROUP BY V.Vendor_Name
HAVING Avg_Between >= 1.5
ORDER BY Avg_Between DESC;
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't recognize column aliases in the `having` clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Vend_Date_Avgs AS
    SELECT V.Vendor_Name, AVG(I.Invoice_Due_Date - I.Invoice_Date) AS Avg_Between
    FROM Vendors V JOIN
         Invoices I
         ON V.Vendor_ID = I.Vendor_ID
    GROUP BY V.Vendor_Name
    HAVING AVG(I.Invoice_Due_Date - I.Invoice_Date) >= 1.5
    ORDER BY AVG(I.Invoice_Due_Date - I.Invoice_Date) DESC;
```

Note the use of proper `JOIN` syntax.